# Can we change the color of the title which is pressed only in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a list of title which is in text. I can change the color of title which in pressed but all the title's color changes.Can I change the the pressed titles only?
I have stored intial color this way

```
Color color = Colors.yellow;
     child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: state.posts.length,
                itemExtent: 300.0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final item = state.posts[index];
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                         setState(() {
                    color = Colors.black;
                  });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Text(
                          item.title,
                          style: TextStyle(color: color),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

[image: The title is in list this way]

Comment: you need to have an individual color state for each title just like you have individual posts stored in a list.

Comment: just add isTapped variable in your model and check if isTapped true then change the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of colors with the same length of your titles, and when you press you can use the same `index` of the `titles` to change the color.

```
/// declare outside build function
List<Color> titleColors = [];


if(colors.isEmpty) {
 for(String title in titles) {
   colors.add(Colors.yellow);
 }
}
     child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: state.posts.length,
                itemExtent: 300.0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final item = state.posts[index];
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                         setState(() {
                    titleColors[index] = Colors.black;
                  });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Text(
                          item.title,
                          style: TextStyle(color: titleColors[index]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see several solutions for this.you can create a separate stateful widget for this or you can use state management method(like provider).

Issue is here

```
setState(() {
                color = Colors.black;
              });
```

when we click one button the whole list view is rebuild using the colour we given.For that we need to keep the main widget state stable and change the list view child state.

try this.first create a list item stateful widget.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListItem({Key key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> {
  Color color = Colors.yellow;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            color = Colors.black;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text(
            item.title,
            style: TextStyle(color: color),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then add this to your list view.

```
ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: state.posts.length,
            itemExtent: 300.0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = state.posts[index];
              return ListItem();
            },
          );
```

this will work.You want to pass the item value to that widget.You have to create a constructor variable and pass it to that ListItem widget.